# Boto3 AWS TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, boto3

I have below code

```
import boto3
client = session.client('ec2')
response = client.describe_iam_instance_profile_associations()
```

> > > print(response)
> > > {'IamInstanceProfileAssociations': [{'AssociationId': 'iip-assoc-0c7941c0858c84652', 'InstanceId': 'i-xxx', 'IamInstanceProfile': {'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::xxxx:instance-profile/xxx', 'Id': 'xxx'}, 'State': 'associated'}], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '15bdc08e-ff66-431e-968e-1930557847ef', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '15bdc08e-ff66-431e-968e-1930557847ef', 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains', 'vary': 'accept-encoding', 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'date': 'Wed, 27 Jul 2022 22:04:12 GMT', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

I would like to get info from output

so i tried

```
  for key in response:
...   print (key)
```

I get response

Also for

```
> for r in response['IamInstanceProfileAssociations']:   print
> (r['InstanceId'] , r['AssociationId'])
```

With Above also i get expected response.

Now i need to get InstanceId & ARN of the instance profile, so i tried below but i got an errro 'TypeError: string indices must be integers'

Any suggestions pls ? i checked nested dictionary pages from google & other but not able to find any solution.

```
     for r in response['IamInstanceProfileAssociations']:
...   #print (r['InstanceId'] , r['AssociationId'])
...   for i in r['IamInstanceProfile']:
...     print (i['Arn'],r['InstanceId'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `i` is a string than you cannot access the position `Arn`

Here is a example showing how you can get the instanceId and Profile's Arn:

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = client.describe_iam_instance_profile_associations()

for association in response['IamInstanceProfileAssociations']:
    print((association['InstanceId'], association['IamInstanceProfile']['Arn']))
```

Using you example the output must be the following:

```bash
('i-xxx', 'arn:aws:iam::xxxx:instance-profile/xxx')
```